# Which NoSQL products support parallel query processing?

Tags: parallel-processing, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I'm going to use a NoSQL product(specially Cassandra or Hbase) for a warehouse application. I didn't found anything useful about which product support parallel query processing(on a single box and also cluster) for range queries. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Apache Hive..It could be a better choice for your use case instead of Hbase or Cassandra..It provides full parallel processing as Hive queries get converted into MapReduce jobs under the hood allowing us to achieve high parallelism..Also Hive provides us data warehousing capability on top of a Hadoop cluster along with SQL like features..That could be quite helpful if you are coming from a SQL background..You can setup Hadoop on a single machine and start using Hive on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

With anyone that uses MapReduce framework. Or you can do it using Hadoop thas is a java framework to MapReduce technique.

I suggest MongoDB